# Cobertura page is empty/unknown after deploying to Gitlab's pages

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages, jest-junit

To run the test locally, I use this:

```
"test-ci": "jest --runInBand webapp/test/ivw --config ./jest.config.js --watchAll=false",
```

In the terminal, I have the coverage report fine, and this also generates de Cobertura page:

[image]

I have 2 stages in my pipeline, one for the unit testing and another one to publish this coverage page:

```
unit:
  script:
    - npm run test-ci
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  cache:
    paths:
      - coverage/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - junit.xml
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml

    pages:
      stage: coverage
      dependencies:
        - unit
      script:
        - mv coverage/ public/
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - public/
```

This is taken from here:

https://gist.github.com/rishitells/3c4536131819cff4eba2c8ab5bbb4570

The thing is that it publishes the page but this has an unknown coverage:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a relative path (not explained in Gitlab documentation):

```
artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage
```